# If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]a_n = 1$ and $a_n$ subsequence converges/diverges do we know that $a_n$ in convergent/divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We also assume that $(a_n) \gt 0$.
What if $a_n$ has a subsequence divergent to infinity to convergent to 0?

My feeling is that if subsequence is divergent, then whole sequence diverges, since we can take $a_n = n$, but I can't think if any way to prove that. And what about subsequence converginig to 0?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A subsequence of which of your sequences?

Comment: Your question is really unclear.

Comment: We know that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive terms. And I'm wondering what do we know about it if it's subsequence is convergent/divergent and the limit in the title holds.

Comment: The condition $(a_n)^{1/n}\to 1$ only tells you that $a_n$ is not **exponentially** decaying or growing. Any non-convergent sequence with a non-exponential behavior is not detected by this condition; it is the case of Kavi Rama Murthy's example.

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=n$ for $n$ even and $1$ for $n$ odd. Then $a_n^{1/n} \to 1$ and $a_{2n} \to \infty$ but $a_{2n-1}$ doesn't.